# How can I compare two lists in Groovy

Tags: groovy

How can I compare the items in two lists and create a new list with the difference in Groovy?

Comment: You need to say what you mean by "difference". Is the order important? Are multiple copies important?

Comment: Do you mean the exclusive disjunction between two lists? i.e.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Collections intersect might help you with that even if it is a little tricky to reverse it. Maybe something like this:

```
def collection1 = ["test", "a"]
def collection2 = ["test", "b"]
def commons = collection1.intersect(collection2)
def difference = collection1.plus(collection2)
difference.removeAll(commons)
assert ["a", "b"] == difference
```

Answer (score 61):

I'd just use the arithmetic operators, I think it's much more obvious what's going on:

```
def a = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "baz"]
def b = ["foo", "qux"]

assert ["bar", "baz", "baz", "qux"] == ((a - b) + (b - a))
```

Answer (score 15):

I assume the OP is asking for the [exclusive disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) between two lists.

(**Note:** Neither of the previous solutions handle duplicates!)

If you want to code it yourself in Groovy, do the following:

```
def a = ['a','b','c','c','c'] // diff is [b, c, c]
def b = ['a','d','c']         // diff is [d]

// for quick comparison
assert (a.sort() == b.sort()) == false

// to get the differences, remove the intersection from both
a.intersect(b).each{a.remove(it);b.remove(it)}
assert a == ['b','c','c']
assert b == ['d']
assert (a + b) == ['b','c','c','d']    // all diffs
```

One gotcha when using lists/arrays of ints. You may have problems due to the polymorphic method `remove(int)` vs `remove(Object)`. [See here for a (untested) solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534146/properly-removing-an-integer-from-a-listinteger).

**Rather than reinventing the wheel**, you should just use a library (e.g. `commons-collections`):

```
@Grab('commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1')

import static org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.*

def a = ['a','b','c','c','c'] // diff is [b, c, c]
def b = ['a','d','c']         // diff is [d]

assert disjunction(a, b) == ['b', 'c', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a list of numbers, you can do this:

```
def before = [0, 0, 1, 0]
def after = [0, 1, 1, 0]
def difference =[]
for (def i=0; i<4; i++){
    difference<<after[i]-before[i]
}
println difference //[0, 1, 0, 0]
```