# Properly removing an Integer from a List<Integer>

Tags: java, collections, overloading

Here's a nice pitfall  I just encountered.
Consider a list of integers:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(5);
list.add(6);
list.add(7);
list.add(1);
```

Any educated guess on what happens when you execute `list.remove(1)`? What about `list.remove(new Integer(1))`? This can cause some nasty bugs.

What is the proper way to differentiate between [`remove(int index)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)), which removes an element from given index and [`remove(Object o)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)), which removes an element by reference, when dealing with lists of integers?

---

The main point to consider here is the one [@Nikita mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534146/properly-removing-an-integer-from-a-listinteger/4534152#4534152) - exact parameter matching takes precedence over auto-boxing.

Comment: A: the real issue here is that someone at Sun somehow thought having (immutable) wrapper classes around primitives was smart and later on someone thought that having auto-(un)boxing was even smarter... **AND THAT PEOPLE KEEP USING LAME DEFAULT APIs WHEN BETTER ONES EXIST**.  For a lot of purposes there are **way better** solution than *new Arraylist<Integer>*.  For example Trove provides things a *TIntArrayList*.  The more I program in Java (SCJP since 2001), the less I use wrapper classes and the more I use well-designed APIs (Trove, Google, etc. comes to mind).

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Java always calls the method that best suits your argument. Auto boxing and implicit upcasting is only performed if there's no method which can be called without casting / auto boxing.

The List interface specifies two remove methods (please note the naming of the arguments):

- `remove(Object o)`
- `remove(int index)`

That means that `list.remove(1)` removes the object at position 1 and `remove(new Integer(1))` removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list.

Comment: Picking a nit: `Integer.valueOf(1)` is better practice than `new Integer(1)`. The static method can do caching and such, so you'll get better performance.

Comment: Peter Lawrey's proposal is better and avoids unnecessary object creations.

Comment: @assylias: Peter Lawrey's  proposal does the exact same thing as decitrig's proposal, only less transparently.

Comment: @MarkPeters My comment was about `new Integer(1)`, but I agree that `Integer.valueOf(1)` or `(Integer) 1` are equivalent.

Answer (score 70):

You can use casting

```
list.remove((int) n);
```

and

```
list.remove((Integer) n);
```

It doesn't matter if n is an int or Integer, the method will always call the one you expect.

Using `(Integer) n` or `Integer.valueOf(n)` is more efficient than `new Integer(n)` as the first two can use the Integer cache, whereas the later will always create an object.

Comment: it would be nice if you could explain why that is the case :) [autoboxing conditions...]

Comment: By using casting, you ensure the compiler sees the type you expect. In the first case '(int) n' can only be of type *int* in the second case '(Integer) n' can only be of type *Integer*.  'n' will be converted/boxed/unboxed as required or you will get a compiler errors if it cannot.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know about 'proper' way, but the way you suggested works just fine:

```
list.remove(int_parameter);
```

removes element at given position and

```
list.remove(Integer_parameter);
```

removes given object from the list.

It's because VM at first attempts to find method declared with *exactly* the same parameter type and only then tries autoboxing.

Answer (score 7):

`list.remove(4)` is an exact match of `list.remove(int index)`, so it will be called. If you want to call `list.remove(Object)` do the following: `list.remove((Integer)4)`.

Comment: Thanks Petar, a simple `(Integer)` cast like you wrote above seems to be the easiest approach for me.

Comment: When using your last approach, it seems to return a boolean. When trying to stack multiple removes I get the error that I cannot call remove on a boolean.

Answer (score 5):

> Any educated guess on what happens when you execute list.remove(1)? What about list.remove(new Integer(1))?

There is no need to guess.  The first case will result in `List.remove(int)` being called, and the element at position `1` will be removed.  The second case will result in `List.remove(Integer)` being called, and the element whose value is equal to `Integer(1)` will be removed.  In both cases, the Java compiler selects the closest matching overload.

Yes, there is potential for confusion (and bugs) here, but it is a fairly uncommon use-case.

When the two `List.remove` methods were defined in Java 1.2, the overloads were not ambiguous.  The problem only arose with the introduction of generics and autoboxing in Java 1.5.  In hind-sight, it would have been better if one of the remove methods had been given a different name.  But it is too late now.

Answer (score 2):

Note that even if the VM did not do the right thing, which it does, you could still ensure proper behaviour by using the fact that `remove(java.lang.Object)` operates on arbitrary objects:

```
myList.remove(new Object() {
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    int k = ((Integer) other).intValue();
    return k == 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: This "solution" breaks the contract of the `equals` method, specifically (from the Javadoc) "It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.". As such it is not guaranteed to work on all implementations of `List`, because any implementation of List is allowed to swap the x and the y in `x.equals(y)` at will, since the Javadoc of `Object.equals` says that this should be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Simply I did like following as suggested by #decitrig in accepted answer first comment.

```
list.remove(Integer.valueOf(intereger_parameter));
```

This helped me. Thanks again #decitrig for your comment. It may help for some one.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is the trick.

Let's take two examples here:

```
public class ArrayListExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Collection<Integer> collection = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    collection.add(1);
    collection.add(2);
    collection.add(3);
    collection.add(null);
    collection.add(4);
    collection.add(null);
    System.out.println("Collection" + collection);

    arrayList.add(1);
    arrayList.add(2);
    arrayList.add(3);
    arrayList.add(null);
    arrayList.add(4);
    arrayList.add(null);
    System.out.println("ArrayList" + arrayList);

    collection.remove(3);
    arrayList.remove(3);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("After Removal of '3' :");
    System.out.println("Collection" + collection);
    System.out.println("ArrayList" + arrayList);

    collection.remove(null);
    arrayList.remove(null);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("After Removal of 'null': ");
    System.out.println("Collection" + collection);
    System.out.println("ArrayList" + arrayList);

  }

}
```

Now let's have a look at the output:

```
Collection[1, 2, 3, null, 4, null]
ArrayList[1, 2, 3, null, 4, null]

After Removal of '3' :
Collection[1, 2, null, 4, null]
ArrayList[1, 2, 3, 4, null]

After Removal of 'null': 
Collection[1, 2, 4, null]
ArrayList[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now let's analyze the output:

1. When 3 is removed from the collection it calls the `remove()` method of the collection which takes `Object o` as parameter. Hence it removes the object `3`.
   But in arrayList object it is overridden by index 3 and hence the 4th element is removed.
2. By the same logic of Object removal null is removed in both cases in the second output.

So to remove the number `3` which is an object we will explicitly need to pass 3 as an `object`.

And that can be done by casting or wrapping using the wrapper class `Integer`.

Eg:

```
Integer removeIndex = Integer.valueOf("3");
collection.remove(removeIndex);
```