# JavaFX2.2 not all table columns showing data with PropertyValueFactory?

Tags: java, javafx-2, tablecolumn

Goodevening everyone,

I stumbled on a rather strange problem today and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. It's about binding table columns with a PropertyValueFactory. I created the table view and table columns in FXML and set the appropriate fx:id's with Scene Builder.

Now the problem is that some columns are showing the expected data and other columns are just empty. I add the items to the table view with following code when a user presses a button:

```
ObservableList<User> olUsers = DA_User.getUsers();
tbl_MC_Manage_Users.getItems().addAll(olUsers);
```

I know for sure that the user objects in olUsers contain all the data needed (tested it with a for loop and System.out.println)

I get a result like this: (<text> representing the column headers)

```
<disabled>   <username>    <title>    <lastname>    <firstname>   <address>   <zip>    <city>
false        (empty)       Mr.        (empty)       (empty)       address1    (empty)  city1
false        (empty)       Miss       (empty)       (empty)       address2    (empty)  city2
```

So for some reason colums username, lastname, firstname, zip are not showing any data...

Some parts of the controller:

```
//declaration (these are the fx:id's connected to my table colums)
@FXML private TableView<User> tbl_MC_Manage_Users;
@FXML private TableColumn<User,Boolean> tc_MC_Manage_Disabled;
@FXML private TableColumn<User,String> tc_MC_Manage_Username;
@FXML private TableColumn<User,String> tc_MC_Manage_Title;
@FXML private TableColumn<User,String> tc_MC_Manage_Lastname;
@FXML private TableColumn<User,String> tc_MC_Manage_Firstname;
@FXML private TableColumn<User,String> tc_MC_Manage_Address;
@FXML private TableColumn<User,String> tc_MC_Manage_ZipCode;
@FXML private TableColumn<User,String> tc_MC_Manage_City;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
...
//setting the binding on the table columns at initialize();
    tc_MC_Manage_Disabled.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, Boolean>("disabled"));
    tc_MC_Manage_Username.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("username"));
    tc_MC_Manage_Title.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("title")); 
    tc_MC_Manage_Firstname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("firstname"));
    tc_MC_Manage_Lastname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("lastname"));  
    tc_MC_Manage_Address.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("address"));
    tc_MC_Manage_ZipCode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("zipcode")); 
    tc_MC_Manage_City.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("city"));
...
}
```

Here are some parts of the User class

```
private SimpleBooleanProperty disabled = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
private SimpleStringProperty username = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private SimpleStringProperty title = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private SimpleStringProperty lastname = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private SimpleStringProperty firstname = new SimpleStringProperty("");
//... (same for the others)

//getters
public boolean isDisabled() { return disabled.get(); }
public String getTitle() { return title.get(); }
public String getUsername() { return username.get(); }
public String getLastName() { return lastname.get(); }
public String getFirstName() { return firstname.get(); }
//... (same for the others)

//setters
public void setDisabled(boolean value) { disabled.set(value); }
public void setUsername(String value) { username.set(value); }
public void setTitle(String value) { title.set(value); }
public void setLastName(String value) { lastname.set(value); }
public void setFirstName(String value) { firstname.set(value); }  
//... (same for the others)
```

Sorry for the loads of code, but I really don't see why only a few columns are getting their data.. I hope someone can point me in the right direction :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your setter is named `getFirstName` then property is `firstName` with capital "N". Try next:

```
tc_MC_Manage_Disabled.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, Boolean>("disabled"));
tc_MC_Manage_Username.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("userName"));
tc_MC_Manage_Title.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("title")); 
tc_MC_Manage_Firstname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("firstName"));
tc_MC_Manage_Lastname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("lastName"));  
tc_MC_Manage_Address.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("address"));
tc_MC_Manage_ZipCode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("zipCode")); 
tc_MC_Manage_City.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("city"));
```

Also I would advise you to add `property` methods to `User` class:

```
public StringProperty titleProperty() { return title; }; // etc
```

it will allow your table to reflect data changes. See 2nd part of [Binding JavaFX 2 TableView elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692654/binding-javafx-2-tableview-elements/11017471#11017471)

Comment: Hah how could i have missed that... Thanks for the swift and clear answer Sergey!

Comment: I was having trouble with setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("first")) where first is a property.  Your tip helped me a lot!  I created public SimpleBooleanProperty firstProperty()  and everything worked.  Thank you Sergey!!