# Invoking overloaded method with less specific argument

Tags: java

`java.util.Vector` has methods:
`remove(int index)` and
`remove(Object o)`

I have:

```
vector<Integer> a;
int b=3;
```

I want:

Invoke method `remove(Object o)` with `b` variable. 
Writing `a.remove(b)` obviously invokes `remove(int index)`

Thanks in advance, Maciej

Comment: possible duplicate of [Properly removing an Integer from a List<Integer>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534146/properly-removing-an-integer-from-a-listinteger)

Comment: `a.remove((Integer) 3);` or `a.remove((Integer) b);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a.remove(Integer.valueOf(b));
```

Should work.  An `Integer` will be resolved as a reference type first, and match `remove(Object)`, before autoboxing is considered to call `remove(int)`.

From the [Java Language Spec, 15.2.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2):

> ### Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature
>
> The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution **without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion**, or the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the second phase.
>
> The second phase (§15.12.2.3) performs overload resolution while **allowing boxing and unboxing**...

Comment: Wow, thanks. This may not explain how to invoke overloaded method with less specific argument but solves my problem :)