# How to remove value from integer arraylist.ANDROID

Tags: java, android, arraylist, int

I created an arraylist for Integer values.

```
 List<Integer> xpos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

adding the integers to the arraylist as follows

```
 int bt_x=10; 
 xpos.add(bt_x);
```

Now how to remove single value ie. how to remove an integer from the arraylist.
We can remove string arraylist with arraylist.get(i).remove. but how to remove the integer arraylist.

Comment: It's in the documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29
It would be nice of you to check *anything* before asking a question. Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ArrayList.remove(java.lang.Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) method. like

```
xpos.remove(Integer.valueOf( premitive int value ));
```

if you want to remove `bt_x` then use

```
xpos.remove(Integer.valueOf(bt_x));
```

***Do not forget to cast int to Integer. If you do not do, it will remove the element at given value.***

---

And yes, [Properly removing an Integer from a List<Integer>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534146/properly-removing-an-integer-from-a-listinteger) should be read.

Comment: actually i need to remove the whole element.

Comment: yes added for the same... :)

Answer (score 2):

Use remove() method of arraylist to remove the object from arraylist.. 
It takes two types of arguments one is object type another is integer type..

```
remove(Object o)

xpos.remove(10);
```