# Undesired behavior of ArrayList remove() in Java

Tags: java, collections

I have following two scenarios:

**1. int value as parameter**

```
int intNum = 2;
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.remove(intNum);
System.out.println(list.size());
// output: 2
```

**2. long value as parameter**

```
long longNum = 2;
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.remove(longNum);
System.out.println(list.size());
// output: 3
```

I am passing 2 as the value in both cases, but I am getting a different size value of the List. What is the actual reason for this behavior?

[Properly removing an Integer from a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534146/properly-removing-an-integer-from-a-listinteger) does not explain about build-in data type having same value but having behavior differently as asked above

Comment: Now that you see that list.remove(2) is removing element at index 2 and not integer 2, you should make a point to explicitly cast to "int" or "Integer" or you only risk to confuse yourself.

Comment: This could be a nice question for a tech interview.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Autoboxing**

The `list.remove` method is overloaded, and the two different signatures are used for different purposes. One, `list.remove(int)`, removes an item based on its index, and the other one, `list.remove(Object)`, removes an item based on object equality. 
Your first situation triggers the first type, and your second example (with a `long longNum`), triggers the second type, autoboxing the `long` primitive to a `java.lang.Long` object. This is not equal to the `java.lang.Integer` (autoboxed) values added to the list, and thus will not remove anything from the list and the size will remain same.

Comment: And the reason `Object` overload is chosen in the second case is because `long` cannot be converted to `int`. `Object` overload is the only one that can possibly apply,

Comment: Even if the first situation triggered the second type, the result would be different.

Answer (score 5):

From the List.remove() [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) :

> remove(int index) Removes the element at the specified position in
>   this list (optional operation).
>
> remove(Object o) Removes the first occurrence of the specified element
>   from this list, if it is present (optional operation).
>
> removeAll(Collection c) Removes from this list all of its elements
>   that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation).

If you second example is indeed a long, it won't be removed (since it uses the second remove method).

Answer (score 5):

Be careful: The first one removes the `Integer` at `index = 2`. See [`ArrayList.remove(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-)

The second one tries to remove an object with [`ArrayList.remove(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-), but the object you want to remove does not exist because it's a `Long` object.

Answer (score 4):

The `List` interface contains two `remove()` methods - `remove(Object)` and `remove(int)`.

The implementation of `remove(Object)` in Java 6 is as follows:

```
public boolean remove(Object o) {
if (o == null) {
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    if (elementData[index] == null) {
        fastRemove(index);
        return true;
    }
} else {
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {
        fastRemove(index);
        return true;
    }
    }
return false;
}
```

The implementation of `remove(int)` in Java 6 is:

```
public E remove(int index) {
RangeCheck(index);

modCount++;
E oldValue = (E) elementData[index];

int numMoved = size - index - 1;
if (numMoved > 0)
    System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
             numMoved);
elementData[--size] = null; // Let gc do its work

return oldValue;
}
```

In your first example, you're actually calling the `remove(int)` method, which removes the object at the specified index. In this case, you specified index 2, which is actually the value "3".

In your second example, you're calling the `remove(Object)` method, since there isn't a `remove(long)` method and a `long` won't be converted into an `int`. Based on the implementation of the `remove(Object)` method, it looks for object equality. Since your list contains objects of type `Integer` and you're providing a `Long`, nothing will match it.

The following method is probably a better example of what's happening:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list;

    System.out.println("Removing intNum");
    int intNum = 2;
    list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    System.out.println("List = " + list);
    list.remove(intNum);
    System.out.println("List = " + list);

    System.out.println("Removing longNum");
    long longNum = 2;
    list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    System.out.println("List = " + list);
    list.remove(longNum);
    System.out.println("List = " + list);
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
Removing intNum
List = [1, 2, 3]
List = [1, 2]
Removing longNum
List = [1, 2, 3]
List = [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

Calling List.remove() with an int argument will match the signature `remove(int index)` and the item on index `list[2]` will be removed regardless if the list has an Integer item with value of 2.

Calling List.remove() with an long argument will cause the compiler to do auto-boxing into a Long object and match the signature `remove(Object o)`.  The list will iterate, asking if o.equals(each item) and as was mentioned before, Long does not equal Integer.

Answer (score 2):

When you were doing `list.remove(intNum);` it was performing the `remove(int index);` signature of the `List` class, which remove the item of the given index.

However when you did `list.remove(longNum);` (considering you meant `longNum` to be `long`), it performed the `boolean remove(Object o);` signature of `List` class, which checks if the object is present in the list, and if yes removes it.

Since the list is an `Integer` list it could not find the object and did not remove anything, and that is why the second result is 3, nothing is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

List in Collection has two overloaded methods 
1. public E remove(int index)
2. public boolean remove(Object o)

In your case **second method** gets called. since you are passing long (implicit casting to **Long wrapper** class so Object class ).

Now List.remove(longNum) removes the element with the lowest index i such that (longNum==null ? get(i)==null : longNum.equals(get(i) ) ) (if such an element exists).

Now in Your case when the counter came at second position (i.e i=1). longNum.equals(get(1)) returns **false** because get(1) returns the Object of java.lang.Integer with value=2 and longNum is an instance of java.lang.Long with value=2. So equals method returns false thus it does not delete the element.

You can check the type of the value by its class Name

```
   System.out.println(" Element Value :"+list.get(1));
   System.out.println(" Element Class :"+list.get(1).getClass());
```