# Removed always last elements from array list

Tags: java, arraylist

This is my code:

```
for (int i=0; i<mListOfItemsToDelete.size(); i++) {
            receivedMessages.remove(mListOfItemsToDelete.get(i).intValue());
            Log.e("position:", mListOfItemsToDelete.get(i).toString());
        }
        mListOfItemsToDelete.clear();
```

`receivedMessages` contains all items (MessagesModel) of messages which I am using in ListView.
`mListOfItemsToDelete` contains list of items index to remove from `receivedMessages` (e.g. `[4, 2, 1]` - always sorted and reversed).

And `receivedMessages.remove(mListOfItemsToDelete.get(i).intValue());` always removed elements from the end of `ArrayList` (e.g. if I choose 2 elements, it removes 2 elements from the end). This line of code makes me crazy - have you any idea what can help to delete items correctly?

EDIT:
I found something very strange in my Logs after input it in my code:

```
private void deleteSelectedMessages() {
        Log.i("arrayIN_:", receivedMessages.toString());
        for (int i=0; i<mListOfItemsToDelete.size(); i++) {
            //TODO: receivedMessages.remove delete last elements, not selected...
            receivedMessages.remove(Integer.parseInt(mListOfItemsToDelete.get(i).toString()));
            Log.e("position:", mListOfItemsToDelete.get(i).toString());
            Log.i("arrayFOR" + i + ":", receivedMessages.toString());
        }
        Log.i("arrayIN:", receivedMessages.toString());
        mListOfItemsToDelete.clear();
    }
```

And my logs (I choose items with indexes 1 and 2 - my `ArrayList` has got 5 elements, 0-4 in index speaking):

```
04-04 16:48:29.536 5829-5829/app.com.mmm I/arrayIN_::
[app.com.mmm.models.MessageModel@3ae1bbc, 
app.com.mmm.models.MessageModel@cfd4745, 
app.com.mmm.models.MessageModel@17ec8e9a, 
app.com.mmm.models.MessageModel@2847d3cb, 
app.com.mmm.models.MessageModel@231f37a8]

04-04 16:48:29.536 5829-5829/app.com.mmm E/position:: 2

04-04 16:48:29.536 5829-5829/app.com.mmm I/arrayFOR0:: 
[app.com.mmm.models.MessageModel@3ae1bbc, 
app.com.mmm.models.MessageModel@cfd4745, 
app.com.mmm.models.MessageModel@2847d3cb, 
app.com.mmm.models.MessageModel@231f37a8]

04-04 16:48:29.536 5829-5829/app.com.mmm E/position:: 1

04-04 16:48:29.536 5829-5829/app.com.mmm I/arrayFOR1:: 
[app.com.mmm.models.MessageModel@3ae1bbc, 
app.com.mmm.models.MessageModel@2847d3cb, 
app.com.mmm.models.MessageModel@231f37a8]

04-04 16:48:29.536 5829-5829/app.com.mmm I/arrayIN:: 
[app.com.mmm.models.MessageModel@3ae1bbc, 
app.com.mmm.models.MessageModel@2847d3cb, 
app.com.mmm.models.MessageModel@231f37a8]

04-04 16:48:29.536 5829-5829/app.com.mmm I/arrayOUT:: 
[app.com.mmm.models.MessageModel@3ae1bbc, 
app.com.mmm.models.MessageModel@2847d3cb, 
app.com.mmm.models.MessageModel@231f37a8]
```

Note that `arrayOUT` is placed one below place where I call mentioned method...

It deletes correctly from `ArrayList`, but why my `ListView` delete always last elements?!

Comment: `receivedMessages.remove(0);` always removes the first element... Are you doing that within the for loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properly removing an Integer from a List<Integer>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534146/properly-removing-an-integer-from-a-listinteger)

Comment: Yes, I know it should remove first element... But it removes always last element - in debug mode I see that. If I choose 3 elements it (`receivedMessages.remove(0);`) removes 3 last objects...

Comment: I want to remove object from position (index) 0 e.g. and it still removes object from last position...

Comment: You should show us the type of `receivedMessages`. Also note that if `mListOfItemsToDelete` is not in descending order the indices will be off after the first remove anyways.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the debugger correctly to step line by line through the code? I noticed you had an Android tag, so just logging things is not true debugging

Comment: can u post the declarations of both your lists here?

Comment: `ArrayList<MessageModel> receivedMessages;`. `ArrayList<Integer> mListOfItemsToDelete;`. And I think yes, I use it properly cause `Log` shows right values (indexes) to delete, but it still deletes objects from the end... I have `mListOfItemsToDelete` in descending order as I mentioned (sorted and reversed).

Comment: I think after each deletion you make your receivedMessages arraylist size is one less than is original size and your logic for making deletion on basis of indexes is not a good approach.You must be having unique id's for all messages in your model class. Try deleting them on basis of id's.

Comment: @Nidhi, no it's not. I delete elements from `ArrayList` in descending order to avoid that, so there is not a chance for that problem.

Comment: Guys, have you got any idea to resolve this problem (cause I still have got it)?

Answer (score 0):

> For me this works :

```
 ArrayList<String> some_data=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> indexes_to_delete=new ArrayList<Integer>();

 some_data.add("one");
        some_data.add("two");
        some_data.add("three");
        some_data.add("four");
        some_data.add("five");

        indexes_to_delete.add(4);
        indexes_to_delete.add(2);

        for(int i=0;i<indexes_to_delete.size();i++) {
            some_data.remove(indexes_to_delete.get(i).intValue());
        }
```

> My some_data now contains "one","two" and "four"

Comment: I have got the same code (only difference is type of `some_data` which is `MessageModel` not `String`... That shows that my code seems to be good. Am I right?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:
receivedMessages.remove(mListOfItemsToDelete[i]);

Comment: but this is `ArrayList`, I can get element only using: `mListOfItemsToDelete.get(i)`

Comment: int indexToRemove = mListOfItemsToDelete.get(i);
receivedMessages.remove(indexToRemove);

the data type of mListOfItemsToDelete is Integer, either change it to 'int' or use above code, it should work for you.