# Arraylist not removing object correctly?

Tags: java

I have some code.

```
     @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            System.out.println(counter.get(0));

            fileHolder.remove(counter.get(0));

            try {
                        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("videoGameDatabase.txt");
                        for (int i=0;i<fileHolder.size();i++) {

                        writer.write(fileHolder.get(i));

                        if(i < fileHolder.size()-1) writer.write("\r\n");

                        }

                        writer.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(FinalProject.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

        }
    });
```

Here, I am trying to delete an element in an array list. When I try to use this button to delete the entry, it does not work. Counter's first element's value is 1.

However, when I do:

```
           fileHolder.remove(1);
```

it works perfectly fine, yet both values are 1.

Why does the first one not work but the second one does?

Comment: Please update the question with all of the code necessary to reproduce the issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: can you show us the type of fileholder and counter. I suppose arraylist but wich datatype

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534146/properly-removing-an-integer-from-a-listinteger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One word: [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). The Java Collections Framework automatically boxes primitive values with their corresponding object, e.g. `int` is auto-boxed as an `Integer` before it is stored in a `Collection` such as an `ArrayList`. This causes ambiguity when using a `List<Integer>` because there are two remove methods, namely `remove(int)` and `remove(Object)`.

**Solution:** You should use an explicit cast to call the correct `remove` method when using an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

- Use `list.remove((Integer)x)` when removing by value
- Use `list.remove((int)x)` when removing by index

*Note:* Do not use `list.remove(new Integer(x))`. This unnecessarily creates a new `Integer` instance every time it is called. Instead, use the explicit cast (as shown above) or the `Integer.valueOf` method; these both take advantage of the autoboxing cache.

Comment: I tried this:

fileHolder.remove((Integer)counter.get(0));

and it still did not work :/

Comment: Could you please capture the return value, as in `boolean retVal = fileHolder.remove((Integer)counter.get(0));`. Was it `true` or `false`?

Comment: Actually, i changed the Integer to an int and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Please review the [Javadocs for ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). ArrayList has **two** remove methods, one of which takes an `int`, and removes at an index. The other takes an `Object`.

If you have stored integers in the `ArrayList`, and then attempt to remove by an `int`, you will remove by the *index*, not the *object*.

You need to carefully review the code for what is being returned. If `counter.get(0)` returns an int, you will then remove the object at the specified index.

Comment: counter does return an int. How can I remove the element? :/

Comment: @elemein, is the counter returning the *index* that should be removed? If so, you should be able to do `fileHolder.remove((int)counter.get(n));`. If it is returning the *value* that is supposed to be removed, you should be able to do `fileHolder.remove((Integer)counter.get(n));`. Though others may disagree, I would probably do something more like `int idx = counter.get(n); fileHolder.remove((int)idx);` or `Integer val = counter.get(n); fileHolder.remove((Integer)val);` to make more clear the intent and the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how you read/store values from/in an array. Maybe there's a problem - reading always first value....