# RemoveIf with lambda expression to remove only one occurence of integer

Tags: java

I need to remove only one occurence of an integer in a ArrayList of integers. My code right now removes *all* integers with a specific value.

```
list.removeIf(s -> s.equals(data));
```

If I have for example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> i = new ArrayList<Integer>();

i.add(1);
i.add(1);
i.add(3);
i.add(5);
```

and I want to remove only the first 1 or the second 1. Not both.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: What did you expect from `removeIf`? Of course it removes all elements for which this predicate resolves to `true` (as explained in its documentation).

Comment: @Zabuza Eh, this is what I've done so far? Its a lambda expression.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534146/properly-removing-an-integer-from-a-listinteger

Comment: Then you might precise your question and explain that you are searching for a way to achieve it and this was your attempt. Because at the moment, at least to me, it sounds more that you are confused why this code yields the observed result instead of the expected.

Comment: Did you find any other methods that start with "remove" in the `List` interface that remove only one occurrence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

Use the `List#remove` method. That is exactly what it was made for, from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)):

> Removes the **first occurrence** of the specified element from this list, if it is present (optional operation). If this list does not contain the element, it is unchanged. [...]

```
boolean wasRemoved = list.remove(data);
```

---

### Removing ints

However, you might have a minor issue here. Your data type is `Integer` and `data` is probably of type `int`. And there is already a method with the signature `List#remove(int)` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#remove(int))) which will remove the element at the given **index**, not the element itself.

You can bypass this by explicitly boxing your `data` to an `Integer`, which is what you actually have stored in the list:

```
boolean wasRemoved = list.remove((Integer) data);
```

Or directly make the `data` variable of type `Integer` instead of `int`.

Comment: Since it's an Int, the OP needs to Cast the value or it will remove by index.

Comment: @Sedrick True. Unfortunately this information was added afterwards to the question. I will update my answer.

Comment: Is casting to `Integer` equivalent to `Integer.valueOf`? I'm just curious if the `Integer` value *might* be cached after casting.

Comment: @JacobG. Good question. `Integer.valueOf` clearly uses the cache (see [zgrepcode](https://zgrepcode.com/java/openjdk/10.0.2/java.base/java/lang/integer.java#L-1046)). Boxing to `Integer` does too (see [JLS§5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)) "*If the value p being boxed is [...] an integer in the range -128 to 127 inclusive [...]. It is always the case that a == b"*. Also see [Weird Integer boxing in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130311/weird-integer-boxing-in-java).

Answer (score 4):

Just use remove method from the `list.remove(new Integer(data))`, by the implementation you can see that it removes the first element then exits:

```
for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {
         fastRemove(index);
         return true;
    }
```