# ListIterator.PreviousIndex Returning A One-Element Integer Array Instead of Int?

Tags: java, iterator, integer, return-type

I am writing a program in which at one point, I am iterating through a list of "buckets" (a nested list of strings). As I do so, I need to keep track of the indices of specific elements within the buckets.

To do so, I have resorted to creating a second 2D list object where each inner list stores the int index value of an element that needs to be tracked.

Because this second list gets sorted later on in my code, I want to dedicate the first element of each inner list to storing the index of the bucket it was responsible for tracking the elements of.

I thought I could do so by using the listiterator's method of "previousIndex()" because it says it returns an int value. But instead, it returns a 1-element int array containing the int I want, rather than just the int itself. This completely messes up my code and I can't seem to access that element when it's stored this way.

[A debugging output showing the enemies list with 3 levels instead of 2 for the first element of the nested list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOPdY.png)

[A debugging output from later in the execution showing that elements added later do not get entered in list form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ssOg.png)

[A compiler error in a different section of code caused by the remove method thinking it is being given an object rather than an integer index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc031.png)

```
public static ArrayList<List<Integer>> isItPossible(String word, LinkedList<List<String>> buckets) {
        ListIterator<List<String>> bucketIterator;
        ListIterator<String> wordIterator;
        List<String> bucket;
        ArrayList<List<Integer>> enemies;
        
        enemies = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        bucketIterator = buckets.listIterator();
        
        while(bucketIterator.hasNext()) {
            bucket = bucketIterator.next();
            wordIterator = bucket.listIterator();
            enemies.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
            enemies.get(enemies.size() - 1).add(bucketIterator.previousIndex()); //adds a list with the element I need, but I just need the element, not the list????

        while(wordIterator.hasNext()) {
            if(!isCompatible(word, wordIterator.next())) {
                enemies.get(bucketIterator.previousIndex()).add(wordIterator.previousIndex());
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Sweeper I'm not sure that it being an empty list should matter. If an int goes into an empty list, then the first element of the list should just become that int. The int shouldn't wrap itself up into a new list that's not defined anywhere and then add itself for some unknown reason. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying?

Comment: Oh I think you seem to have read your debugger wrong. It's not showing 3 levels of list. It's only 2 levels of list, shown on 3 lines. The first line shows the name of the outer list - `enemies`. The second line shows an element of the outer list, at index `[0]`, which happens to be another list, as shown on the second column. The third line shows an element of the inner list, which is an integer, as shown on the second column. This shouldn't "mess up your code". If your code doesn't work, it's not because of the list having 3 levels instead of 2, because it only has 2 levels.

Comment: @Sweeper I've added a 2nd screenshot and another bit of code to clarify. As you can see from the 2nd screenshot, elements added after the first don't have dropdowns, because they're just Integers, not lists. I can access those elements normally and easily.

Additionally, the extra bit of code shows that the elements added after the first are added in the exact same way, they're just added by a different listiterator. Could the type of listiterator somehow cause this?

Comment: This still just seems like a quirk of your debugger. The inner lists definitely have integers in them, not other lists. I suggest that you mention what debugger you are using, to help people reproduce the problem. Also note that having a dropdown doesn't automatically mean it's a list. In my debugger (IntelliJ IDEA), all `Integer` objects have dropdowns. I can expand them and see their value.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't seem to access that element when it's stored this way"? Can you show some sample inputs and outputs of what you are trying to do, so that we can understand where exactly your code is wrong, rather than fixating on "`previousIndex` returns an list", because that clearly does not happen here.

Comment: @Sweeper sure, I'm using Eclipse IDE's default debugger. I've added a 3rd screenshot now, where you can see I'm having a compiler error. enemies.get(i).get(0) SHOULD return an integer value that can be used as an index position, since I've highlighted in the rest of the post that it is meant to be storing integers. But the compiler thinks it's not getting an index, and it's getting an object instead, causing it to choose the wrong remove method.

Comment: Aha, so that's the problem. You should have shown that section of the code too! Does casting it to `int` work? `remove((int)enemies.get(i).get(0))`. [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4534158/5133585).

Comment: 0_0 alright yeah that did it. thanks for linking the related answer as well. I see now my issue was assuming that Integer would function a lot more like a primitive and a lot less like an object