# SoapUI - Error in asserting SQL query response with response Json of REST API

Tags: sql, json, groovy, soapui, assert

I have a REST API that retrieves a list of values. I am performing a SQL Query that retrieves the values from the Oracle DB. I am trying to find a way to compare/assert that the retrieved values from the API are the same ones with the ones stored in DB. My code is:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult

context.setProperty("crudManager", new CrudManager())
CrudManager.log = log

// CrudManager
public class CrudManager {

// Check Retrieved Games 
    public void checkRetrievedGames(testRunner, testCase){
        // Get Test Step's Response.
        def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def response = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Get Games").getPropertyValue("response")
    def responseJson = slurper.parseText(response)

    //Get the Games stored in DB
    def gameCode = "GM_CD"
   def query = "SELECT $gameCode FROM SCHEMA.PGM"
   def array = new OracleConnector().select(query)
   System.out.println(array);
   def gameCodesList = Arrays.asList(array)

    // Assertions - Compare response with DB.
    assert responseJson == gameCodesList
    }

}
```

When calling checkRetrievedGames function I get error Message:
{Assertion failed: assert responseJson == gameCodesList | | | | | [[[GM_CD:15000], [GM_CD:15100], [GM_CD:15200], [GM_CD:15300], [GM_CD:15550], [GM_CD:15600], [GM_CD:15900], [GM_CD:16000]]] | false [15000, 15100, 15200, 15300, 15900, 16000] error at line: 5}

The retrieved json file is:
 [
   15000,
   15100,
   15200,
   15300,
   15900,
   16000
]

And the sql query response is:
GM_CD
15000
15100
15200
15300
15550
15600
15900
16000

From what I understand I have to somehow remove the "GM_CODE:" from the retrieved list of the sql query.
Thank you for your time

Comment: Sample input data used for compare would help.

Comment: Sample data input added!

Comment: Thank you for the update. Is sql result is string or list as well? Is `GM_CD` prefix for all values?

Comment: GM_CD is the Column Name where the values 15000, 15100, etc are. And it is unique.

Comment: Ok, but was it a list ?

Comment: Yes, you can sort it however you want. a simple sql query.

Comment: If you use groovy script, this does exactly what you want - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713665/opposite-of-intersect-in-groovy-collections

Comment: Thank you for pointing this to me, I've just read it. I guess the only assertion needed then is: assert responseJson == grr ?

Comment: With the above assertion, when calling checkRetrievedGames function I get a response: {-> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[{GM_CD=15000}, {GM_CD=15100}, {GM_CD=15200}, {GM_CD=15300}, {GM_CD=15550}, {GM_CD=15600}, {GM_CD=15900}, {GM_CD=16000}]' with class 'java.util.ArrayList' to class 'groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult(groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult, )}

Comment: May be you can update the question with latest script along with stacktrace, probably that might help.

Comment: Thanks for the help, updated Original Post.

Comment: It does not show the stacktrace properly to locate the problem in the script or not an updated script present in the question.

Comment: I updated the code and the new error message of the assertion that is being retrieved, hope that helps.