# How to manipulate and compare lists using Groovy

Tags: list, groovy

I have 3 lists that I need to compare and manipulate. Here are the lists, for example:

```
def list1 = ['abc', '123','789'];
def list2 = ['456', 'abc', '123'];
def list3 = ['mil', 'len', 'nium'];
```

I need to compare values of list1 and list2 and if they are the same, I need to return the corresponding item with the same index of list1 found in list3.

Using the example above, since list1[0] and list2[1] are the same, I need to return the list3 value, 'mil'.

The lists' value will also be dynamic so how will I be able to do it in groovy?

Comment: Please add the code, what you have tried and what errors you got so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about it on [Groovy Docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html). You can find common elements by

```
def commons = collection1.intersect(collection2)
```

and find element in third list using index from first list by `indexOf`.
It may be useful as well [Comparing lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544258/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-groovy)

Something like

```
def commons = list1.intersect(list2)
def indexes = []
commons.each {
    indexes << list1.indexOf(it)
}
def values = []
indexes.each {    
    values << list3[it]
}
```

Of course it can be done in many ways, easier, but it works too in some cases